# How to use "codepage 932" characters in CMD batch? (fullwidth solidus)

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, codepages

I am trying to read a folder name in my batch file that contains the **fullwidth solidus character (／)** which I have gathered belongs to the **codepage 932**.

I have tried to enter chcp 932 into my batch but the console reports "invalid codepage". How do I enable this codepage in my batch file? Using cp1252 or utf8 has proven unsuccessful.

Note: I'm okay with the console window showing garbled text, as long as the actual script works.

Comment: Do you have Jp language support on that computer?

Comment: What's your problem ? Any error message ?

Comment: @CristiFati was wanting to see if there was a way to do it without having to install Japanese language support. I simply use the solidus in folder names since folder names can't support normal solidus (slash)

Comment: @SachaDee the problem is that the folder isn't read wherefore no data is being fed to the recipient app (i'm trying to feed a folder name into Winamp playlist using CLAMP).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you script around it using a wildcard?  If the folder is named `folder／name` (where `／` is Unicode char 0xff0f), do something like

```js
for /d %%I in ("folder?name") do set "folder=%%~I"
```

And now you can refer to it by `%folder%` without having to change your codepage.

Man, DejaVu Sans Mono (my console font) doesn't even have a glyph for that character.

---

Interestingly, `for /F` converts the Unicode solidus to a non-extended **/**.  Check this out:

[image: fullwidth solidus tests]

And if I use `for /f` to set a variable to the output of `powershell "[char]0xff0f"` then do `if "%var%"=="/"` (0x2f), it evaluates true.  Does `for /f` somehow know **／** and **/** are visually similar, or is that just coincidence?  I don't see how it could be a coincidence, as **／** (0xff0f) has no bytes in common with **/** (0x2f).

Well, ultimately, one thing is made clear by these experiments.  You can't use `for /f "delims=" %%I in ('dir /b /a:d "folder?name"')` to populate your variable unless you `chcp 65001` to change your codepage to Unicode.  It has to be `for /d`.

Comment: This is interesting! I won't try it for a while, but it's good that you posted a workaround for those interested in a solution without switching codepage

Answer (score 0):

Batch files .BAT and .CMD only allow ANSI character sets when writing the file itself.

The other answer shows how to bring in the UNICODE characters from a command that supports the necessary codepage.

You can store the special characters in a UNICODE text file and bring them in through the use of the "|", "<", or FOR commands.